# Python 3.6 cannot import gnuradio (3.7.9)

Tags: python, numpy, gnuradio

I know Gnuradio 3.7.9 supports python2.7 and gnuradio 3.8 is the one supporting python3, however i find myself in a peculiar situation. I currently have to use gnuradio 3.7.9 since at work we are still developing with it, however the program i'm trying to develop needs numpy1.17 that is supported by python3.6.

So if i run the program with python (2.7) i cannot acces to the function i need, however if i run it with python3.6 it cannot import gnuradio module.

Question is: is there any way to import gnuradio to python3 even if the version of gnuradio installed is 3.7.9? or is there any way to install numpy 1.17 on python 2.7?

Comment: No, if a package supports Python 2.7 only, it won't work on Python 3, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Radio 3.7 is Python2-only; there's no way around that short of writing a Py3 wrapper for GNU Radio – which is hard, trust me, I should know.

If your required numpy version needs Python3, well, you can't use GNU Radio 3.7.

3.7 is a legacy release series, and 3.7.9 is positively ancient, anyways.

So, update to GNU Radio 3.8 and you can use Python3.